# Is a Dockerfile necessary for Google Container Builder or should cloudbuild.yaml cover all use cases?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Assuming a workflow where all container building happens on Google Container Builder(GCB), is a Dockerfile even necessary?

For example to build custom containers where we would like to have some packages installed or copy files from the local filesystem, I see most examples GCB still using Dockerfile (e.g. https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders ) - is this because its not possible using cloudbuild.yaml?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The easiest tool to compose a Docker container image is still using the `docker build` command with a `Dockerfile`. It is very common to have a `cloudbuild.yaml` file with a single step that uses the `Dockerfile` in the root of your source, like so:

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['build', '-t', 'gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/my-image', '.']
images: ['gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/my-image']
```

So, for constructing a final container image, using `docker build` and a `Dockerfile` is the recommended approach. It will let you easily install dependency packages, for instance.

You can use your `cloudbuild.yaml` to perform other operations, before or after your `docker build` step. For instance, if you wanted to create a binary without packaging your SDK into the final image, it is easy to do that with `cloudbuild.yaml`. Or, if you wanted to pull in some extra assets from Cloud Storage using `gsutil`.

Container builder will also let you build and push as many images as you like, all tied to the same commit of your git repo (and they can include the commit sha in the image tag too) by having many steps that run `docker build`. You could even run these builds in parallel.

See https://cloud.google.com/container-builder/docs/api/build-steps for how to add steps for arbitrary things.

Comment: I use `RUN npm run build:ssr` in my `Dockerfile` and can successfully access the created directory `dist/browser` afterwards within the `Dockerfile`, but when I try to deploy the `dist/browser` directory from the `cloudbuild.yaml` the directory doesn´t exist. Do they have something like a different scope?
I also created a question for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66670594/google-cloud-build-firebase-deployment-error-public-directory-dist-browser