# Google Cloud Build - firebase deployment error: "public directory 'dist/browser' does not exist, can't deploy hosting to site PROJECT-ID"

Tags: angular, firebase, docker, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I´m trying to simultaneously deploy my Angular Universal web-app to Cloud Run (for SSR) and Firebase Hosting (for caching). The deployment to Cloud Run works fine and I followed this guide (https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/deploying-builds/deploy-firebase#using_the_firebase_community_builder) to enable Firebase deployment with Google Cloud Build.

However, whenever I run `gcloud builds submit --config=cloudbuild.yaml` the error: `public directory 'dist/browser' does not exist, can't deploy hosting to site PROJECT-ID` is thrown during the Firebase deployment step in the `cloudbuild.yaml`.

`cloudbuild.yaml`:

```yaml
steps:
  # build image
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/SERVICE-ID', '.' ]
  # push image
  - name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
    args: ['push', 'gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/SERVICE-ID']
  # deploy to Cloud Run
  - name: "gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud"
    args: [ "run", "deploy", "SERVICE-ID", "--image", "gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/SERVICE-ID", "--region", "us-central1", "--platform", "managed", "--allow-unauthenticated" ]
  # deploy to Firebase (ERROR HAPPENS HERE Specified public directory 'xx' does not exist, can't deploy hosting to site PROJECT-ID)
  - name: gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/firebase
    args: ['deploy', '--project=PROJECT-ID', '--only=hosting']
images:
  - 'gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/SERVICE-ID'
timeout: 1800s
substitutions:
  _ENV_VARIABLE: development
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:14

# set work directory
WORKDIR usr/src/app

# copy package.json and package-lock
COPY package*.json ./

# install dependencies
RUN npm install

# copy local code to container
COPY . .

# build app
RUN npm run build:ssr

# serve app
CMD ["npm", "run", "serve:ssr"]
```

`firebase.json`

```json
{
...
  "hosting": [
    {
      "public": "dist/browser",
      "ignore": [
        "**/.*"
      ],
      ...
    }
  ]
...
}
```

`error-log`

```
DEBUG: https://storage.googleapis.com:443 "GET /987290120943.cloudbuild-logs.googleusercontent.com/log-93082fbf-1b87-499a-9132-fed5f1c06aad.txt HTTP/1.1" 206 290
DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 206 (read 290 bytes)
Step #3:
Step #3: ←[1m←[37m===←[39m Deploying to 'PROJECT-ID'...←[22m
Step #3:
Step #3: ←[1m←[36mi ←[39m←[22m deploying ←[1mhosting←[22m
Step #3:
Step #3: ←[1m←[31mError:←[39m←[22m Specified public directory 'dist/browser' does not exist, can't deploy hosting to site PROJECT-ID
DEBUG: https://cloudbuild.googleapis.com:443 "GET /v1/projects/PROJECT-ID/locations/global/builds/93082fbf-1b87-499a-9132-fed5f1c06aad?alt=json HTTP/1.1" 200 None
DEBUG: https://storage.googleapis.com:443 "GET /987290120943.cloudbuild-logs.googleusercontent.com/log-93082fbf-1b87-499a-9132-fed5f1c06aad.txt HTTP/1.1" 206 120
DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 206 (read 120 bytes)
Finished Step #3
ERROR
ERROR: build step 3 "gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/firebase" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
DEBUG: https://storage.googleapis.com:443 "GET /987290120943.cloudbuild-logs.googleusercontent.com/log-93082fbf-1b87-499a-9132-fed5f1c06aad.txt HTTP/1.1" 416 168
DEBUG: Reading GCS logfile: 416 (no new content; keep polling)
```

Since everything works fine locally, I assume that it may have to do something with `gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/firebase` being in a different container than the service `gcr.io/PROJECT-ID/SERVICE-ID` where perhaps the `dist` folder is created.

**Edit #1:**

I tested creating a folder called "static" in the root of the project and changed the `public` property in `firebase.json` to 'static'. It worked which makes me believe that for some reason the `dist/browser` directory does not exist during the "deploy to Firebase" step in the `cloudbuild.yaml` even though it is created during `RUN npm run build:ssr` of the `Dockerfile`.

**Edit #2:**

I found something not quite adequate (https://stackoverflow.com/a/64215324/8581106) on a similar problem. However, the suggestion seems to be to also run the build command `npm run build:ssr` before the Firebase deployment in the `cloudbuild.yaml` to make sure the `dist/browser` directory exists. But I´d really like to avoid serving one build on Cloud Run and deploy a new build to Firebase, because Angular uses unique hashes for `.js` and `.css` files everytime and I feel like this could lead to caching problems.

**Edit #3:**

I created an image to visualize my problem better (see image below). I´m new to docker and Cloud Build, but I feel like this is the procedure when I run `gcloud builds submit --config=cloudbuild.yaml`. I don´t understand why the `dist/browser` exists in the `Dockerfile` scope but not in the `cloudbuild.yaml` scope.

[image: procedure when creating container]

Comment: Can you please share the log output of `gcloud builds submit --config=cloudbuild.yaml -verbosity="debug"` in order to confirm the step where the issue occurs?

Comment: @FaridShumbar I´ll post the log in the next hours. However, I feel like I know where the issue occurs, but I don´t know how to fix it. The problem is probably that the `dist/browser` directory only exists in the `Dockerfile` context where `npm run buid:ssr` is called, but not in the `cloudbuild.yaml` where I want to deploy the `dist/browser` directory to Firebase. Maybe the image above shows this better.

Answer (score 1):

According to https://stackoverflow.com/a/66714846/8581106, I can not access the `dist/browser` directory within the `cloudbuild.yaml`, because the directory is created in a different context through the `Dockerfile`.

Currently, the only solution I found was to deploy an empty folder to Firebase Hosting immediately after deploying the build to Cloud Run. As I understand it, the user now makes a Request to Firebase Hosting and gets the Response if it is already cached on the Firebase Hosting server. If the requested data is not cached the `rewrites` in the `firebase.json` allow to get the rendered data from Cloud Run and caches it afterwards if possible.

Although it seems to work, I don´t know if the files from Cloud Run are correctly cached on Firebase Hosting and in addition, the Lighthouse scores in terms of performance are way worse because of the missing compression for texts, images and files which was automatically managed by Firebase Hosting before. Still, at the moment this is the most viable solution.