# Google Cloud Build - Different scopes of Dockerfile and cloudbuild.yaml

Tags: docker, google-cloud-build

I recently asked a question about why I get the error `Specified public directory 'dist/browser' does not exist, can't deploy hosting to site PROJECT-ID` when I´m trying to deploy to Firebase Hosting in my `cloudbuild.yaml`. However, since I find the question too bloated with information I tried to break it down.

I created a simple image to visualize what happens when I call `gcloud builds submit --config=cloudbuild.yaml`. So why can´t I access the directory `dist/browser` from `cloudbuild.yaml` even though it is processed after the `Dockerfile` where the directory `dist/browser` is created?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cloud Build is best conceptualized as a series of functions (steps) applied to data in the form of a local file system (often just `/workspace` as this is a default volume mount added to each step, but you can add other volume mounts) and the Internet.

Output of each function (step) is self-contained unless you explicitly publish data back to one of these two sources (one of the step's volume mounts or the Internet).

In this case `docker build` consumes local files (not shown in your example) and generates `dist/browser` in the image that results but this folder is **only** accessible within that image; nothing is added to e.g. `/workspace` that you could use in subsequent steps.

In order to use that directory subsequently:

- Hack a way to mount the (file system of the) image generated by the step and extract the directory from it (not advised; possible not permitted).
- You'd need to run that image as a container and then `docker cp` files from it back into the Cloud Build's (VM's) file system (perhaps somewhere on `/workspace`).
- Not put the directory in an image in the first place (see below)

#### Proposal

Instead of `docker build`'ing an image containing the directory, deconstruct the Dockerfile into a series of Cloud Build steps. This way, the artifacts you want (if written somewhere under one of the step's volume mounts), will be available in subsequent steps:

```
steps:
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
  args:
  - install
- name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
  args:
  - run
  - build:ssr # Presumably this is where dist/browser is generated?
- name: firebase
  args:
  - deploy # dist/browser
```

> **NOTE** Every Cloud Build step has an implicit:
>
> ```
> - name: some-step
>   volumes:
>   - name: workspace
>     path: /workspace
> ```

#### Proof

Here's a minimal Cloud Build config that uses a volume called `testdir` that maps to the Cloud Build VM's `/testdir` directory.

> **NOTE** The example uses `testdir` to prove the point. Each Cloud Build step automatically mounts `/workspace` and this could be used instead.

The config:

- Lists the empty `/testdir`
- Creates a file `freddie.txt` in `/testdir`
- Lists `/testdir` now containing `freddie.txt`

```
options:
# volumes:
#   - name: testdir
#     path: /testdir

steps:
  - name: busybox
    volumes:
      - name: testdir
        path: /testdir
    args:
      - ash
      - -c
      - "ls -1a /testdir"
  - name: busybox
    volumes:
      - name: testdir
        path: /testdir
    args:
      - ash
      - -c
      - 'echo "Hello Freddie" > /testdir/freddie.txt'
  - name: busybox
    volumes:
      - name: testdir
        path: /testdir
    args:
      - ash
      - -c
      - "ls -1a /testdir"
```

> **NOTE** Uncommenting `volumes` under `options` would remove the need to reproduce the `volumes` in each step.

The edited output is:

```sh
gcloud builds submit \
--config=./cloudbuild.yaml \
--project=${PROJECT}

# Lists (empty) /testdir
Starting Step #0
Step #0: Pulling image: busybox
Step #0: .
Step #0: ..

# Creates /test/freddie.txt
Starting Step #1
Step #1: Already have image: busybox
Finished Step #1

# List /testdir containing freddie.txt
Starting Step #2
Step #2: .
Step #2: ..
Step #2: freddie.txt
Finished Step #2
```

Comment: Thank you for the in-depth answer, it gave me a better perspective. I already thought of putting the `npm install` and `npm build:ssr` (which creates the `dist/browser` directory) in the `cloudbuild.yaml`, however, then I´d still need to run `npm run serve:ssr` to launch the express server. Can I also do this from the `cloudbuild.yaml` and if yes, what do I even need the `Dockerfile` for anymore?

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad to hear it helped. Why do you need to launch the Express server? Isn't that what Firebase is doing for you?

Comment: If you can get away with `firebase deploy` from the assets built under Cloud Build then you do **not** need a Dockerfile. If you were deploying to e.g. Cloud Run, you'd need to give it a container image and so then you'd need the Dockerfile (or similar) to create the image that you could then give to the Cloud Run service to run. With Firebase, you don't need a Dockerfile. Actually Cloud Build is poorly explained by Google and it could be used for arbitrary processing, there's no need to either use Dockerfiles or produce container images.

Comment: I use Cloud Run to serve rendered HTML files (SSR) and Firebase Hosting for caching. So I basically rewrite all initial requests from Firebase Hosting to Google Cloud run when the requested files aren´t yet cached. That is why I´d like to deploy the same `dist/browser` directory to Firebase which I also serve from Cloud Run. Because every new build creates new unique hashes for .js and .css files and probably messes with caching. Sorry if I wasn´t clear from the beginning, but I didn´t think this issue would go so deep.

Comment: I still have the overall issue, but you answered this question. At least now I understand why I can´t access the served `dist/browser` directory. I just have to find a different way.

Comment: If you perhaps know any possibility to access the `dist/browser` directory of the image `gcr.io/$_ENV_PROJECT/$_SERVICE_ID` from the `cloudbuild.yaml` before deploying to Firebase I would be were thankful. Or maybe you know a helpful link to this topic.